# phone book script

Tags: bash, scripts

Good day I am a newbie in Linux scripting, and I am now exploring LINUX then suddenly I was motivated to create a program and I want to create a phone book program I am now done creating the menu that contains an add, lookup, list, change, delete and quit.

In the add menu, I was able to enter the name, address, phone number,and email-address. But I don't know how to store those data I inputted. Can someone help me how to do it? please? thanks in advance.

```
#!/bin/bash
# add
echo "Enter Name: "
read name
echo "Enter Address: "
read address
echo "Enter Phone Number: "
read phone number
echo "Enter Email Address: "
read email address
```

Comment: Not sure if bash is the most convenient language to create such a thing...

Comment: but my friend can create a program like that and he did'nt want to tell me how can i make an add script to store the data. :(

Comment: Do you want us to create the script or just to show you the way to save user input from `read` ?..

Comment: can you help me to create the script for me to enable me to add the data? thankyou

Comment: it must store in the list menu not in the read command.. i used read so i can input a certain text and display it.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the Ubuntu community!

The simplest way to store anything on *nix, is as a file, which can easily be done with pipes.

So for example:

```
#!/bin/bash
# add
echo "Enter Name: "
read name
echo "Name: $name" >> Phone\ Book

echo "Enter Address: "
read address
echo "Address: $address" >> Phone\ Book

echo "Enter Phone Number: "
read phone
echo "Phone: $phone" >> Phone\ Book

echo "Enter Email Address: "
read email 
echo "Email: $email" >> Phone\ Book
echo " " >> Phone\ Book
```

`$` is for calling variables. When you did `read email`, you created the `$email` variable. You can check its value by typing `echo $email`

`>>` is a redirection operator that appends to a file and creates it if it doesn't exist. It's different from `>` which overwrites anything already in the file if one exists.

`""` are weak quotes. Variables are expanded inside such quotes. In strong quotes (`''`), everything is interpreted literally, meaning if you put a `$` in there, it would not reference a variable.

`\` is for escaping characters. Notice how `Phone\ Book` has this? Well this means that I escaped the space character, so the file I created is literally `Phone Book`. Without it, it would be just create a file called `Phone`

---

If you really want to get a better platform for programming, you should download the Ubuntu SDK, and try developing this program using a language called "QML" aka "QtQuick".

Bash Programming is still important though, so it's good for you to learn those skills as well.

Comment: awww thank you very much sir i will try it right a way... im not really familiar with the use of pipes but i know the basic.

Comment: Make sure you accept the answer if it works for you, to help keep our stack exchange clean. Its also important to upvote solutions that work for you to help other users who will look at this page. Also, make sure your title is formatted as a question.  "Phone book script" is too vague. And finally; make sure you spell check your question, use proper punctuation, and so on so it does not have to be edited after ~

Comment: i want to store the data in the list menu how can i do it?

Comment: List menu? You will have to be more specific. Menu's typically refer to an actual gui, and the drop downs such as http://i.imgur.com/YcuSbet.png.  You do realize that the data is stored in a file "Phone Book" that is created when you run the script, right?